# XML file with &auml;

Tags: java, xml

I have a XML file that roughly looks like this:

```
<customer>
    <name>M&uuml;ller</name>
</customer>
```

I parse the file using following code:

```
File xmlFile = new File("file.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile)
```

And get the error that the entity `&uuml;` is referenced but not declared. What I want is that the entry is being read but not parsed in any way, I want to get the value as it is written in the file.

How do I do that?

Comment: I had the same problem for some weeks. But i do not found a good solution. I have use xslt transformation to transform the html entity to an xml entity and then parse the modified file.

Comment: Does the XML reference a DTD that defines that entity, or is the XML itself buggy?

Comment: The reason why you get an error is because `&uuml;` is not a standard XML entity reference. In XML, there are only [five standard entity references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML): `&amp;`, `&quot;`, `&apos;`, `&lt;`, `&gt`. Things like `&uuml;` are HTML entity references, but they are not defined in XML.

Answer (score 6):

I tried setting:

```
dbFactory.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
```

but this doesn't work.

If you can't modify your xml content (using UTF-8 the xml can contain u umlaut), you might be able to add a DTD:

```
<!DOCTYPE definition [
<!ENTITY uuml "&#xfc;">
]>
```

If you can't modify your xml file, load the xml contents and prepend the DTD:

```
String dtd = "<!DOCTYPE definition [\n<!ENTITY uuml '&#xfc;'>\n]>\n",
            contents = <load xmlFile>;
Reader reader = new StringReader(dtd + contents);
InputSource src = new InputSource(reader);
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(src);
```